# How to batch split feature classes using Arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, error-000728

I want to bath split analysis tool using Arcpy . I have some feature classes in a feature dataset.I want to Split All of feature classes uisng a shapefile but after split two feature classes, the runtime error raised( **Runtime error : Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000728: Field Province does not exist within table Failed to execute (Split)**). My input feature has a province field and the result of the split is fine for a feature class but not for all of them .

How can i solve the problem ?

another qestion is that is there any way to change the output featureclasses? for example province name with underline featureclass name.

```
import arcpy 
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/split_test.gdb/split" 
fcl = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() 
for fc in fcl:
    arcpy.Split_analysis("province",fc,"province","D:/output_split.gdb","")
```

Comment: If you are attempting to split your fc features, they should be the first parameter in the Split tool. http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000006000000

Comment: @AlmaThom . the parameters are set in arpy.Split_analysis and split work properly for one feature class but not for all of them

Comment: That is weird, because it shouldn't. With the code you show above, you are telling the tool to split your Province feature class using the fc layer's 'province' field.

Comment: I think you need to add a `print` statement to show which feature class this is bailing on, and then to carefully check that the field is present and called `province` (not `Province` or `PROVINCE`).

Comment: I think we need you to provide more details because your additional question "is there any way to change the output featureclasses?" seems at odds with how Split derives feature class names from the Split field values.

Comment: @PolyGeo .I use print statement and the result show all of feature classes

Answer (score 1):

Would something like [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=37AEB018-1422-2418-A036-CA6D9920F808) work for you? I haven't tried it in 10.1 but it's worked in the past in 10 for me!

Comment: I want to split by location using python